# How to make xlsx can read any file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

I'm using xlsx to read xlsx and convert to json.

this is my code :

```
exports.processingMasterFunder = async (filePath, masterFunderId, filename, done) => {
  try {
    // read spreadsheet file
    const workbook = XLSX.readFile(filePath, {cellDates: true});

    // read spreadsheet section A
    const sectionA = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

    // convert sheet to json data section A
    const outputA = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sectionA);

...
```

It was work perfectly in my local, until I upload to staging the error is occured.
error like this :

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/uploads/New Funder Statement January 2022.xlsx'
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at Object.openSync (fs.js:497:3)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:393:35)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at read_binary (/app/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:3160:44)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at readSync (/app/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:23293:69)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at Object.readFileSync (/app/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:23333:9)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at Object.exports.processingMasterFunder (/app/helpers/processing.js:29:27)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at /app/worker.js:16:14
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at Worker.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/kue/lib/queue/worker.js:230:7)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at Job.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/kue/lib/queue/job.js:706:12)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at multi_callback (/app/node_modules/redis/lib/multi.js:89:14)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at Command.callback (/app/node_modules/redis/lib/multi.js:116:9)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at normal_reply (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:721:21)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at RedisClient.return_reply (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:819:9)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at JavascriptRedisParser.returnReply (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:192:18)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:574:12)
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:274:27) {
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM  errno: -2,
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM  syscall: 'open',
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM  code: 'ENOENT',
3/28/2022 5:48:40 PM  path: '/app/uploads/New Funder Statement January 2022.xlsx'
```

It's weird, xlsx can't read the file that I uploaded and save using multer, but can read the file that already available in path that I push from local.
Multer already write the uploaded file to the path, It's proved by succesfully uploading the file to google cloud and i can download it again from google cloud. It's mean the file in the correct path.

it's just happen in my staging. On local, it's work after I upload file and save using multer, xlsx can read the file without error.

How to solve my problems ?

Comment: it seem that the path you gave to the reader is not correct

Comment: idk but i think the path is correct. Because I try to read the file that already available on the same path, the different is this file's exist because I pushed from local, not uploading and save using multer. And in my local it's work correctly